# Systematically rewiring functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of classes where most methods merely 'rewire' method calls to `self.value`, and return a new instance:

```
class someClass():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__( self.value.__add__(other) )

    def someMethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__class__( self.value.someMethod(*args, **kwargs) )

    def someOtherMethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__class__( self.value.someOtherMethod(*args, **kwargs) )
```

Of course, not all methods inside are like this, but most are.

Instead of having to implement explicitly `someMethod`, `someOtherMethod` and `__add__`, is there a way to  do this systematically? Perhaps with `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`?

---

Here is why subclassing the value's type is not viable :

```
>>> class someClass(int):
    pass
>>> a = someClass(5)
>>> isinstance(a+5, someClass)
False #I need this to be True
```

In order to make that last line return True,  I would have to 'rewire' all operators like before : subclassing doesn't help at all

Comment: if you inherit from the "value class" instead of using it as member, then you don't have to implement the methods. You could read me about inheritance [here](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/)

Comment: @TheFool Most of these 'rewires' are for operators, wouldn't subclassing the value's class mean operators like += or *= would return that class instead of mine ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are doing. Can you try to explain it better with code in your question?

Comment: @TheFool I have added a specific example relating to your proposed solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer, because you still have to list the methods that you want to wrap, but the following makes it a lot easier to wrap a large number of methods, because you just add them to a list of methods to be wrapped:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'<MyClass({repr(self.value)})>'

    
def make_wrappers(cls, methods):
    for method in methods:
        def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
            return self.__class__(getattr(self.value, _method)(*args, **kwargs))
        setattr(cls, method, wrapper)    


make_wrappers(MyClass, ['__add__', '__sub__', 'upper'])

x = MyClass(3)
print(x+2, x-2)  # <MyClass(5)> <MyClass(1)>

y = MyClass('hello')
print(y.upper())  # <MyClass('HELLO')>
```

It does not seem that you can use `__getattr__` to do entirely what you want. This is because if you are trying to evaluate `a+b`, where `a` is an instance of your class, then if you have not defined an `__add__` method but have defined `__getattr__`, then this will raise a `TypeError` and ignore (not call) `__getattr__`. Therefore you cannot use `__getattr__` to wrap "magic methods" such as `__add__` (at least in Python 3).

Note here that the `_method` is used to ensure that value of the variable `method` is bound into the wrapper at the time when it is defined (it is added to the defaults dictionary). If instead you were to use `method` directly inside `wrapper` where `_method` is used, then you would find that every wrapper would use the value of `method` inherited from an outer scope when it is called, which would not be what you want.

Note also that the solution relies on "monkey-patching" the class. This will work. What will *not* work in Python 3 is to monkey-patch *instances* of the class -- for example if you tried to use `setattr` to add a method directly to `x` that does not exist in `MyClass`, then calling it would not work.

Comment: I need to re-read this very carefully and test it, but it seems to satisfy my requirements. Would this work if I put it in a module and imported it ?

Comment: @AmyLucyRose I don't see why not.

Comment: After re-reading this, it does indeed solve my problem. However, is there a way to get rid of the _method kwarg, without the problems you mentionned ? If not it's okay but I think it makes the implementation slightly more confusing. (Hopefully the docstring I added takes care of that, but still, it would be nice if there was a way to get rid of it)

I think I can think of an approach with lambda, I will try implementing that as well and test it

Answer (score 0):

I would use this very basic approach:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        for method_name in ("some_method",
                            "some_other_method"):
            new_method = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.__class__(getattr(self.value, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(self, method_name, new_method)
```

Now you only need a way to give those methods docstrings.

Comment: This doesn't work, but the reason why is quite subtle : For some methods (mostly operators and other dunders), they need to exist at the class level, because \_\_getattr\_\_ and \_\_getattribute\_\_ are bypassed. Furthermore, this makes every single instance much larger in memory, which would scale terribly.